# Usability of Softwares

Tags: after-effects, premiere, adobe

Do Adobe Premiere Pro and Adobe After Effects CS6 still usable for editing? What features will I miss from the latest versions?

Date of question: 24th December 2020

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can be used
But well, it is not possible to explain all the cases, certainly no one can tell you all about them, my dear friend, but in the new series, there has been so much variety and facilities, and fixing bugs, and so on.

It is recommended to work with the same version and scroll a bit on YouTube to see what are the differences with older versions.
Good luck